# Finding a record in an interval in Guava Cache

Tags: java, caching, guava, google-guava-cache

I am evaluating some results with Spring SpEL and I would like to cache those results so I don't have to evaluate expressions with same parameters.

My cached key object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CachedResult {
    private String baseName;
    private Interval interval;

    public boolean isBetweenInclusive(final DateTime date) {
        return interval.contains(date) || interval.getEnd().isEqual(date);
    }
}
```

My solution to find a record with `interval` that covers the given `dateTime`:

```
public String getEvaluatedResult(final String baseName, final DateTime dateTime) {
    return cache.asMap().entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().getBaseName().equals(baseName) && entry.getKey().isBetweenInclusive(dateTime))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

I wanted to make use of `cache.get(key, valueLoader)` method so that it can put values in the cache itself if needed, but I can't think of a way to make use of `isBetweenInclusive` and this method.

My attempt with a comment where I got into problems:

```
public class MyCache {

    private final Cache<CachedResult, String> cache;

    public DefaultRolloverCache(final int expiration) {
        this.cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(expiration, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
    }

    public String getFileName(final String baseName, final DateTime dateTime, final Callable<String> valueLoader) {
        try {
            return cache.get(new CachedResult(baseName, null/*How to find an interval that covers the given dateTime?*/), valueLoader);
        } catch (final ExecutionException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot read fileName from cache with basename: '%s' and dateTime: %s", baseName, dateTime), e);
        }
    }
}
```

I call this method like:

```
cache.getFileName(baseName, new DateTime(), () -> doSlowCalculations(baseName));
```

Ofcourse, since I don't know how to use the mentioned method, I have to use `cache.put(new CachedResult(...))` to put records in the cache myself.

Is there a better way to filter the Cache than calling `asMap` and filtering it like a Map? Can I somehow use the `cache.get(key, valueLoader)` or even Guavas `CacheLoader` so that it can put values in automatically?

As the performance goes, I will have at maximum 5-10 records in it at one time, but I will read a lot from it, so read times are very important to me and I'm not sure if my current implementation that iterates over 5-10 records all the time and checks each of them is the best approach.

Comment: Your approach is probably as good as it gets; iterating over 5-10 records is going to be so fast basically anything else would be slower (and there probably isn't a better way anyway).

Comment: Does iterating over Map entries after calling `asMap` affect expirations differently than calling `cache.get` does? In other words, are these two calls the same if I have 1 record in cache:

`cache.asMap().entrySet().stream().findFirst().get().getValue();`

`cache.get(record);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution after reading the comment Louis wrote:

```
public String getFileName(final String baseName, final DateTime dateTime, final Supplier<String> valueLoader) {
    final Optional<String> cached = cache.asMap().entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().getBaseName().equals(baseName) && entry.getKey().isBetweenInclusive(dateTime))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue);

    if (cached.isPresent()) {
        return cached.get();
    } else {
        final String evaluatedValue = valueLoader.get();
        cache.put(new CachedResult(baseName, intervalCalculator.getInterval(dateTime)), evaluatedValue);
        return evaluatedValue;
    }
}
```